# Basic Financial Data for Non-Governmental Organizations (NGOs)

Tags: data-request, usa, finance, nonprofit, ngo

I'm looking for a data resource that contains financial and/or employment [non-governmental organizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-governmental_organization) (NGOs).

[CharityNavigator.org](http://www.charitynavigator.org) provides this kind of data for charities, but not for NGOs.

For example, I'd like to be able to look up a list of NGOs and find out:

- the number of employees or some other metric of size
- a mailing address
- something with their annual budget or expenses

Does such a data resource exist?

---

*Update:* An interesting article about [Liberating 990 Data](http://www.ssireview.org/blog/entry/liberating_990_data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selected financial information on all entities that file using form 990 with the IRS is public. A variety of datasets can be found in the IRS Statistics of Income (SOI). I would start at this page:

http://www.irs.gov/uac/SOI-Tax-Stats-IRS-Tax-Exempt-Organization-Population-Data

Answer (score 2):

CharityNavigator.org includes a page for every US registered nonprofit. Even if it isn't a rated charity, there is basic data included via a link to the org's Form 990. If the org is large enough (such that it files the full 990), then you'll find those data points on its Form 990.

Comment: The tip about the Form 990 is useful. Can you provide a link for the CharityNavigator NGO pages?

Comment: @philsem - I browsed through the site. The full pages user3917 refers to have to be navigated one at a time and the data is displayed in tables/graphs. I do not see any public dump of the data. They have an API, but they charge $499 (basic) and $999 (premium)/month to use it. Their copyright notice says - "All materials contained on this site http://www.charitynavigator.org are protected by United States copyright law and may not be reproduced, distributed, transmitted, displayed, published, or broadcast without the prior written permission of Charity Navigator"

Comment: Thanks @Andrew-OpenGeoCode. Can you point me to one page for one NGO?

Comment: @philshem . This is a link to the first listing in the A-Z directory.

Comment: @philshem - oops. here's the link: http://www.charitynavigator.org/index.cfm?bay=search.summary&orgid=6082#.VE6VY2eYacw

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@user3917's answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/3907/1511), I navigated to the IRS 990 page called **[Exempt Organizations Business Master File Extract (EO BMF)](http://www.irs.gov/Charities-&-Non-Profits/Exempt-Organizations-Business-Master-File-Extract-EO-BMF)**, which provides CSV files on the state level (50+) and by region (4 files in total). The data includes address and financial data.